# How to load JSON to D3 in Tree Diagram

Tags: html, json, d3.js

I am a real dumb with HTML and JavaScript, so please excuse any dumbness.

I am using D3 Tree Diagram, but I need to load a JSON file instead of writing it inside the JS script, which the name of the file to be loaded will be chose by the user in a `select` tag. Here's the [D3 code](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8323795)

First, how can I load/read a JSON file, lets say `exampleNodes.json`,

And then, how can I pass the name of the selected `select` tag so that it reads the appropriate JSON?

Thanks for your patience, and help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in code

```
var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "children": [
         {
        "name": "Son of A",
        "parent": "Level 2: A"
      },
      {
        "name": "Daughter of A",
        "parent": "Level 2: A"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Level 2: B",
    "parent": "Top Level"
  }
]
  }
];
```

you have to save it on data.json file like

```
{ 
  "treeData" : [ ... your data array ...]

}
```

after that in d3.json() function you will receive this object

```
d3.json("data.json",function(json){

        // do your coding 
       // or  all code put inside one function and call it after data loaded  
});
```

if you are using google chrome than it will gave you error on data reading from json because security Google Chrome not allow read files from file system you can get data in Firefox. to make it run upload your code on some local server. i.e in WampServer or Apache tomcat etc.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, json is what data.json contains huh?, yet, I do not capture anything when i call alert(json). please, could you elaborate a little bit the answer??